# When can I omit dereferencing with the asterisk operator?

Tags: rust

I have a hard time understanding when to use the asterisk operator for dereferencing and when can I omit it.

```
fn main() { a(); b(); c(); d(); }

fn a() {
    let v = 1;
    let x = &v;
    println!("a {}", *x);
    println!("a {}", 1 + *x);
}

fn b() {
    let v = 1;
    let x = &v;
    println!("b {}", x);
    println!("b {}", 1 + x);
}

fn c() {
    let mut v = 1;
    let mut x = &mut v;
    println!("c {}", *x);
    println!("c {}", 1 + *x);
}

fn d() {
    let mut v = 1;
    let mut x = &mut v;
    println!("d {}", x);
    println!("d {}", 1 + x); // error
}
```

The above code sample almost compiles except the last statement where I add one to the the mutable reference `x`. There I get this error:

```
the trait bound `_: std::ops::Add<&mut _>` is not satisfied [E0277]
```

Anywhere else both asterisk and non-asterisk versions are valid and give expected results.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531912/what-is-the-usage-of-the-asterisk-symbol-in-rust

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only add types for which the operator is defined by implementing the `Add` trait. In both examples where you do `1 + *x`, the type of `*x` is `i32` and indeed `i32 + i32` is defined. For convenience there is also an implementation of `i32 + &i32` (and `&i32 + i32` and `&i32 + &i32`) which makes `b` work, but this is *just* for the specific case of one immutable reference, it doesn't extend to, say `&&i32` or `&mut i32`. That's why `d` does not work.

Comment: I see. What do you suggest to use where both forms are allowed and yield the same results? Should I stick to the asterisk everytime, or should I take advantage of the convenience implementations?

Comment: You should use them, that's why they exit. Superfluous dereferencing doesn't clarify the code, it just adds line noise.

Comment: Should the third sentence be "For convenience... which makes **`b`** work..." because `b` is the function with the immutable reference that is not explicitly dereferenced?