# What is the usage of the asterisk symbol in Rust?

Tags: rust, syntax

I'm new to Rust and I don't understand the following piece of code:

```
let mut x = 5;
{
    let y = &mut x;
    *y += 1;
}
println!("{}", x);
```

Explanation from the [Rust site](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/references-and-borrowing.html#mut-references):

> You'll also notice we added an asterisk (`*`) in front of `y`, making it `*y`, this is because `y` is a `&mut` reference. You'll need to use astrisks [sic] to access the contents of a reference as well.

If `*y` is a reference, why does the following code work

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 5;
    {
        let y = &mut x;
        println!("{}", y);
    }
}
```

I know I'm not modifying the value here, but what is the difference and why
would `y += 1;` not work?

Comment: Possibly worth a read: [Auto-dereferencing](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/rust/2574/auto-dereferencing#t=201611101618367290575) (from the Rust documentation section on this site), which explains some of the cases where `*` is not needed.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Found another link may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules

Comment: Related: [What do the ampersand '&' and star '*' symbols mean in Rust?](/q/36335342/2189130)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> If `*y` is a reference

`*y` is **not** a reference. `y` is a reference; `*y` *dereferences* `y`, allowing you access to the referred-to value.

> what is the difference [between `+=` and `println!`]

`println!` is a macro that [automatically references the arguments given to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450399/does-println-borrow-or-own-the-variable). In addition, the [`Display` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) (used via `{}` in the format string) is implemented for all references to types that themselves implement `Display` (`impl<'a, T> Display for &'a T where T: Display + ?Sized`).

Thus, `println!("{}", y);` is actually printing out a reference to a reference to a value. Those intermediate references are automatically dereferenced due to the implementation of `Display`.

`+=`, on the other hand, is implemented via the [`AddAssign` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.AddAssign.html). The standard library only implements adding an integer type to itself (`impl AddAssign<i32> for i32`). That means that you have to add an appropriate level of dereferencing in order to get both sides to an integer.

Comment: Would it be possible to add an implementation of `AddAssign` for `&mut i32`? It seems to be like this would be quite logical, but maybe I'm missing a pitfall.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I do believe it's *possible*, and the `Add` trait does have some precedent. I have a feeling that there's some good reason, but the [RFC lists it under unresolved questions](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0953-op-assign.md#unresolved-questions). Also you might be interested in [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/36380) ^_^

Comment: Ah! Didn't even think to check whether the quote was exact or not :P

Comment: @Shepmaster https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/36380 is pointing to the PR which fixes typo in word. Why this could be interesting?

Comment: @SlavaSemushin you'll note that I directed that comment at Matthieu M., who correctly realized that the quote in OP contained a mistyped word. However, the original source that the quote was from contained the typo (thus why I added `[sic]` to the quote) and then I pointed out to them that the typo has been fixed in upstream, just not published yet.