# How to get the minimum value within a vector in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to display the minimum value within a vector in Rust and can't find a good way to do so.

Given a vector of `i32` :

```
let mut v = vec![5, 6, 8, 4, 2, 7];
```

My goal here is to get the minimum value of that vector without having to sort it.

What is the best way to get the minimum value within a `Vec<i32>` in Rust ?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
let minValue = vec.iter().min();
match minValue {
    Some(min) => println!( "Min value: {}", min ),
    None      => println!( "Vector is empty" ),
}
```

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.min

> ```
> fn min(self) -> Option<Self::Item>
> where
>     Self::Item: Ord,
> ```
>
> Returns the minimum element of an iterator.
>
> If several elements are equally minimum, the first element is returned. If the iterator is empty, None is returned.

I found this Gist which has some common C#/.NET Linq operations expressed in Swift and Rust, which is handy: https://gist.github.com/leonardo-m/6e9315a57fe9caa893472c2935e9d589

Comment: Thanks Dai, I think this is to get the max value, what about the min value ? Because in return I have ```Some(8)``` when I actually need to get only ```8```when I do a ```println!("{:#?}", maxValue);``` since ```println!("{}", maxValue);``` returns an error.

Comment: @octano `println!("{}", maxValue.unwrap());`

Answer (score 23):

```
let mut v = vec![5, 6, 8, 4, 2, 7];
let minValue = *v.iter().min().unwrap();
```

Comment: Fairly new to Rust, but what does the * do here exactly? It works without it as well.

Comment: @CallumMatthews You can find the answer on this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531912/what-is-the-usage-of-the-asterisk-symbol-in-rust

Answer (score 5):

Hi @octano As Dai has already answered, min/max return Option<> value, so you can only match it as in example:

```
fn main() {
    let vec_to_check = vec![5, 6, 8, 4, 2, 7];
    let min_value = vec_to_check.iter().min();
    match min_value {
        None => println!("Min value was not found"),
        Some(i) => println!("Min Value = {}", i)
    }
}
```

[Play ground example for Iter.min()](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=276212e20fb404f3d8c23153a185f31a)

Comment: @aws_apprentice When blandger replied my answer didn't include the `match` part. This was just bad timing.

Comment: There are no rules on this site for duplicate answers. You're welcome to expand your answer to attract up votes, and the key is to post correct answers.

Comment: Yes, the duplicate reason is timing issue, I posted answer and Dai is updated his answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

```
let max = nums.iter().max().unwrap_or(&0);
```

You can use `unwrap_or(value)` to return default value if max not found.