# Is the idiom to find the maximum value in an iterator, and using it, by dereferencing only (Rust)?

Tags: rust, iterator, max

I have gone through a handful of posts on this topic, in Stackoverflow. I am confirming if I have got the essence, correct.

I want to find out the maximum value in a Vector, using Iterator. Because of the way, iterators are implemented in Rust (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58669865/how-to-get-the-minimum-value-within-a-vector-in-rust), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58102574/how-does-one-get-an-iterator-to-the-max-value-element-in-rust)), I understand that I will always receive a reference to the element (if it exists) and not its value.

This doesn't compile.

```
pub struct WorkCard {
    pub worker_id: u32,
    pub largest_sack_moved_by_worker: u128,
    pub sacks_moved: Vec<u128> // collection of duration of each call to API
}

impl WorkCard {
    pub fn new(worker_id: u32, sacks_moved: Vec<u128>) -> WorkCard {
        let mx = sacks_moved.iter().max().unwrap_or(0);
        WorkCard { worker_id, largest_sack_moved_by_worker: mx, sacks_moved }
    }
}
fn main() {
    

    let sacks: Vec<u128> = vec![5,2,9,8,1];
    
    let _worker1 = WorkCard::new(1 /* worker_id */, sacks /* sacks_moved */);
    
    println("Worker {}, moved even a sack of {} KG!", 
            _worker1.worker_id, 
            _worker1.largest_sack_moved_by_worker
    );
    
    
}
```

The compiler clearly indicates what the problem is:

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:9:53
  |
9 |         let mx = sacks_moved.iter().max().unwrap_or(0);
  |                                           --------- ^
  |                                           |         |
  |                                           |         expected `&u128`, found integer
  |                                           |         help: consider borrowing here: `&0`
  |                                           arguments to this method are incorrect
  |
help: the return type of this call is `{integer}` due to the type of the argument passed
 --> src/main.rs:9:18
  |
9 |         let mx = sacks_moved.iter().max().unwrap_or(0);
  |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-^
  |                                                     |
  |                                                     this argument influences the return type of `unwrap_or`
```

Of course, this works!

```
impl WorkCard {
    pub fn new(worker_id: u32, sacks_moved: Vec<u128>) -> WorkCard {
    
        let mx = sacks_moved.iter().max().unwrap_or(&(0 as u128)); // <-- forcing a numeric constant's reference
        WorkCard { worker_id, largest_sack_moved_by_worker: *mx, sacks_moved } // <-- then, dereferencing !
    }
}
```

My question is if I should take it that this is an idiomatic way to grab the maximum (or minimum) value off an iterator. If there is a more pleasant way, I would like to learn that.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021)

NB: Thanks for everybody who has taken time to comment and guide me.

I think I should point out why I had been looking for an idiomatic use for such a common construct.I had been in serious 'C' world for the first decade and a half of my career, and there - as you all know - dereferencing using `*-operator` was (and is) a part of daily ritual. However, as I learn Rust, I realize that using `*-operator` to get a value is not really the norm. In fact, safer and cleaner operators/techniques/idioms exist to bypass that completely, in a overwhelming number of Use-Cases. Thus, was my question, if such a use (use of '*' operator) was OK, with the Rust experts. I had got my job done, yet I inquired because **my own solution** didn't seem **right to me**.  :-P

I am very aware of the power and the inherent danger of using '*' operator. So, I am cautious.

Comment: Although clippy doesn't like it, I would prefer `let mx = sacks_moved.iter().max().or(Some(&0)).unwrap();` here to avoid the ugly casting.

Comment: It indeed looks ugly! That was what I meant, when I inquired about a **more pleasant** way! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because of the way, iterators are implemented in Rust (discussed here, and here), I understand that I will always receive a reference to the element (if it exists) and not its value.

That is not quite true, you receive a reference not because of the way "iterators are implemented in Rust" but because you're using a *borrowing iterator* ([`slice::Iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html), as returned by [`slice::iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter)).

> Of course, this works!

It's not clear to me why you bother with `(0 as u128)`, [`&0` would work fine](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a34f0dc1bdb9fa96223cf36b3529f72a). Even if it did not, `0u128` will provide a concretely-typed constant.

> My question is if I should take it that this is an idiomatic way to grab the maximum (or minimum) value off an iterator. If there is a more pleasant way, I would like to learn that.

Pleasantness is in the eye of the beholder, defaulting to a reference looks fine to me, but you could use an adapter to convert the reference to an owned value, either [`Iterator::copied`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied):

```rust
let mx = sacks_moved.iter().copied().max().unwrap_or(0);
```

or [`Option::copied`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.copied):

```rust
let mx = sacks_moved.iter().max().copied().unwrap_or(0);
```

Comment: I would prefer `copied()`, it also may be little more efficient.

Comment: Thank you, @masklinn, for a detailed answer. Here are my supplementary comments: (1) Your slap on the wrist, pointing out the inexactness in my observation about 'iterators are implemented in Rust' is well-taken. However, I think it is clear from the context what I had intended to say. :-) I had tried to `into_iter()` also and the early consumption of the iterator didn't help matters for subsequent operations on the same vector. So, I had dropped that from the scheme of things.

Comment: (2) `(0 as u128)` is unnecessary to the expert eyes, but that extra cast just makes it a little bit easier for the new entrants to **read the code** easily. I presume the compiler will find that extraneous cast a bit annoying and then will shrug and go generate the most appropriate code ignoring it, anyway. I value conciseness as much as anybody else, but I also want the reader to spend minimum time to understand the code. Please correct me, if I am wrong. And, yes, I could have used `0u128` too.  @masklinn

Comment: (3) The `copied()` should have occurred to me. Thanks for guiding me towards an apt use of it. I have learnt something today. @masklinn